# Toggle between Sandbox mode and Production mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I need clarification and some help for a task at work. We have a dashboard that has 2 modes, Sandbox and Production. I have a toggle that switches between the modes. Shown here: [Sandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzJU0.png) [Production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXDvD.png)

I want to be able to switch views and if possible the APIs I call when I toggle each mode. Please how can I go about this? I would appreciate any help

I created the toggle bottom in the navbar like this:

```
import { Switch, Text } from @chakra-ui/react

const [mode, setMode] = useState(true);
function switchMode() {
  setMode(!mode)
}

<Text fontSize={15} mr={2}>
  {mode ? "Sandbox" : "Production"}
</Text>

<Switch onChange={switchMode} />
```

We have 2 APIs, one for each mode. How can I switch between the two APIs when I toggle the modes?

This is my .env file

```js
VITE_BACKEND_SANDBOX_URL = http://localhost:8000

VITE_BACKEND_PRODUCTION_URL = http://localhost:4000
```

This is how I'm calling the API:

```js
const getAllCustomers = async (rows, page, token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };
  const response = await axios.get(
    `${import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_SANDBOX_URL}/api/v1/customer/paginate-customer?page=${page}&rows=${rows}`,
    config
  );
  return response.data;
};
```

Comment: Share some more relevant code related to how you call the APIs.

Comment: Do you use environments in your project?

Comment: Yes I do @JuniusL

Comment: please share your environments

Comment: I just added some more code. @JuniusL

Comment: I just added some more code. @technophyle

Comment: You can do something like this https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/compassionate-sanderson-tz9hxn?file=%2Fsrc%2Fenvironment.ts%3A10%2C23

Answer (score 0):

You can create an environment file like the following

```
const ENVS =  {
  LOCAL: "local",
  SANDBOX:"sandbox",
  PROD: "prod",
}

const Environments = {
  Sandbox: {
    name: "Sandbox",
    env: "sandbox",
    apiHost: "http://156.21.190.78",
    apiBase: "/api/v1",
  },
  Prod: {
    name: "Production",
    env: "prod",
    apiHost: "http://156.23.190.78",
    apiBase: "/api/v1",
  },
};

const Environment = {
  current: Environments.Prod,
};

const ENV_MATCHERS = {
  [ENVS.LOCAL]: ["localhost", "127.0.0.1"],
  [ENVS.SANDBOX]: ["sandbox"],
};

const isEnv = (hostUrl, environment) => {
  const matchers = ENV_MATCHERS[environment];

  if (!matchers) {
    throw new Error("Critical: Error initializing environment");
  }

  return matchers.find((match) => hostUrl.includes(match)) !== undefined;
};

const initEnv = (host: string) => {
  if (isEnv(host, ENVS.LOCAL)) {
    // Environment.current = Environments.Local;
    return ENVS.LOCAL;
  }

  if (isEnv(host, ENVS.SANDBOX)) {
    Environment.current = Environments.Sandbox;
    return ENVS.SANDBOX;
  }

  Environment.current = Environments.Prod;
  return ENVS.PROD;
};

const reloadEnvironmentConfig = (env = '') =>
  initEnv(env || window.location.host);

reloadEnvironmentConfig();

export { Environment, reloadEnvironmentConfig };
```

As you can see above, we are exporting the Environment and reloadEnvironmentConfig function, which will be used to reload the environment

in your screen import both  Environment and reloadEnvironmentConfig function

```
import React from "react";
import { Environment, reloadEnvironmentConfig } from "./environment";

function App() {
  const [env, setEnv] = React.useState(Environment.current.name);
  return (
    <>
      <p>Current ENV: {env}</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          // reloads the environment 
          reloadEnvironmentConfig(env === "Sandbox" ? "Production" : "sandbox");

          setEnv(Environment.current.name);
        }}
      >
        change env
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can even go further and create an Api class, that manages your api request

```
import { Environment } from "./environment";

export class Api {

  static getUrl() {

    const baseUrl = (Environment.current?.apiHost || '') + (Environment.current?.apiBase || '');

    return baseUrl;

  }

  static get(url, config) {
    const _url = Api.getUrl(url)
    return axios.get(_url, config)
  }
}
```

Then in your get all customers function you do

```
import { Api, } from "./api";

const getAllCustomers = async (rows, page, token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };
  const response = await Api.get(`/customer/paginate-customer?page=${page}&rows=${rows}`,config);
  return response.data;
};
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/compassionate-sanderson-tz9hxn?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A8%2C11)

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I'm quite new to this I'll try to follow your steps. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to handle it.

First and simplest approach is to store the flag whether the current env is sandbox or production in localStorage whenever there's an update, and before calling any API endpoint, check that value each time, update the base URL accordingly. You'd probably want an API config file that pulls data from environment variables and store them.

Psuedo-code:

```
// when toggling
localStorage.setItem('apiEnv', mode);

// api config
const apiConfig = {
  sandbox: process.env.VITE_BACKEND_SANDBOX_URL,
  production: process.env.VITE_BACKEND_PRODUCTION_URL,
};

// when calling
const apiEnv = localStorage.getItem('apiEnv');
const baseUrl = apiConfig[apiEnv];
// and use baseUrl for all API helpers
...
```

Another approach is, you can create a global context that stores the flag while also keeping it in localStorage. This way, you only need to pull the localStorage data once when the app mounts for the first time and work with the context state going forward.